# A few queries regarding Meta-analysis and its subparts using R

Tags: r, self-study, meta-analysis, sensitivity-analysis

As part of a meta-analysis of a disease in R, I received some feedback on the paper of which it is a part by external consultants. I cannot contact them again, and am confused about the advice they have given.
This is part of an undergraduate project, and I am relatively new to meta analysis in general.
I have been given 4 datasets, namely age, sex(male), traction(Bronchiactis) and Honeycombing.
Each dataset contains the following parameters:
Hazard ratio`(HR),`Lower control limit`(LCL)`, Upper control limit`(UCL)` and the Standard Errors`(SE)[of Ln(HR)]` values, and I used the SE values to calculate Variances(`var` in the datasets).
One of the meta analysis on one of the above datasets can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/566619/doubt-regarding-funnel-plot-in-meta-analysis-using-metafor-in-r), (the dataset along with the code I used and the results of the model.)

The parts of the feedback which confused me were,

> 1.Conduct a `Sensitivity analysis` and a `Subgroup analysis`.

What exactly are `sensitivity analysis` and `Subgroup analysis`? Are there any packages in R which will help get these analyses, and are the 4 datasets, containing the parameters I stated above enough for the analyses, or is more data/more parameters needed?

> 2.In the multivariate analysis, add information about the `adjust factor`.

I looked this up and could not find any information about this. What exactly is an `adjust factor` and how can I calculate it?

P.S: Sorry, cannot include the paper here, for copyright reasons.

Comment: I think this is impossible to answer without knowing what they are really asking. There are many, many ways of doing sensitivity analyses. At a complete guess the subgroup analysis involves using all the datasets together with a four-level factor for dataset as a moderator. I suspect when they say multivariate they mean multivariable.

Comment: @mdewey got some clarification, I need to do the sensitivity analysis of publication bias. I ran a standard metafor funnel, and got some results, [here][1].
But how do I proceed from here, to do the sensitivity analysis, for the publication bias?

[1]: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/566619/doubt-regarding-funnel-plot-in-meta-analysis-using-metafor-in-r